# How to access while array outside the loop in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to access while array $row2 outside the loop so that I can compare in if else condition, because $row2 array contains many number. Is there any solution make $row array accessible outside the loop or any other method?

```
<?php
$sql = (" SELECT * FROM result ");
$query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $row2 $row['id'];
}

for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++) {
    if ($i<= $row2) {
        echo "<font color='red'><font size='50px'>".$i."</font></font>"."<br>";
        continue;
    } else {
        echo $i.'<br>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Set `$row = array();` before the while loop, you will be able to read it afterwards.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes Why would it not be available afterwards?

Comment: I don't really understand, what's the purpose of the code? It just doesn't make any sense to me. Maybe context will help.

Comment: You've also got a syntax error here: `$row2 $row['id'];`

Comment: @Mike i am changing color of those number which are available in database and i am saving thode number in $row2 array

Comment: `$row2` is supposed to be an array? If so how would you expect `if ($i<= $row2)` to work?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to loop over two dependent things you need to nest them or else `$row2` will always contain the *last* value in the while loop:

```
<?php

$sql = (" SELECT * FROM result ");
$query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $row2 = $row['id']; // I added an = sign here.

    for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++) {
        if ($i<= $row2) {
            echo "<font color='red'><font size='50px'>".$i."</font></font>"."<br>";
            continue;
        } else {
            echo $i.'<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

If this isn't what you want please clarify your question.

Comment: yes its showing last value but i want to show every value in array that's the real problem

Comment: @Raahull So does this answer do what you would want then?

Comment: no $row contains 1,2,3,4,7
your code out put is 1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

Comment: What is the output supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

Pass your variable to a separate function that performs whatever task you want.

```
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
     MyFunction($row2);
}

function MyFunction($passed_row2_value){
    // perform whatever task you want here.
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This shows with some format the ids retrieved by the query and fills the blanks without format.

```
<?php
$sql = (" SELECT * FROM result ");
$query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

$row2 = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $row2[$row['id']] = true;
}

for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++) {
    if ($row2[$i]) {
        echo "<font color='red'><font size='50px'>".$i."</font></font>"."<br>";
    } else {
        echo $i.'<br>';
    }
}
?>
```